# Search Icon not searching with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I am trying to trigger the search icon to start a search on the result within the search bar but it isn't working. Clicking on it shows its click range but doesn't do anything otherwise. Can anyone help, please thanks

Below isn't the full code but more than what is needed. If you need the full code feel free to ask.

```
class OutlinedTextFields extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchA: false
    };

    this.searchOn = this.searchOn.bind(this);
  }
  searchOn() {
    this.setState({ active: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className="conT" noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          autoFocus={true}
          fullWidth
          className={`${classes.textField} without-padding`}
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.cssLabel,
              focused: classes.cssFocused
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
              focused: classes.cssFocused,
              notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
              MuiOutlinedInput: classes.MuiOutlinedInput
            }
          }}
          label="Search"
          variant="outlined"
          id="custom-css-outlined-input"
        />
        <InputAdornment disablePointerEvents={false}>
          <IconButton className={classes.style} onClick={this.searchOn}>
            <SearchIcon on Click={this.searchOn} />
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(OutlinedTextFields);
```